# How to refactor a code to support multiple versions of hardware?

Tags: c++, embedded, refactoring, software-design

I am working on a new existing code base, where assume a file high_level_feature.cpp is written completely assuming there is v1 version of hardware. Currently it includes header files for v1 HW registers.

I need to add support for v2 version of hardware now, who's header file has the same names of registers as v1, but different offsets and address.

Note: The version is detected runtime and not compile time.

So it's obvious either I need to change the names in header files to be able to add both header files (v1 & v2) and implement the feature in high_level_feature.cpp which would support both v1 & v2 HW.

Is there a better, cleaner way to refactor the code and implement this?

Thanks,
Kimi

Comment: Do you know the version at compile time, or are you creating a program that is supposed to determine the version while running ?

Comment: The APIs have to detect the version runtime and depending on the version it has provide the needed feature.

Comment: You could use namespaces to allow the inclusion of both headers, unless you're talking about #defines.

Comment: yes, there a tons of #define's in the header files.

Comment: You could still make this work by creating a compilation unit for each version.  I.e. you compile one .cpp file for each version, giving them a common interface (superclass).

Comment: I am okay with re-implementing & re-designing everything once for all, if that is the case what SW design is typically best for such use-cases?

Comment: You could rewrite the headers to replace #defines with more sensible c++ mechanisms (enums, typed constants, classes - and namespaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic code shouldn't be coupled to hardware. I advice create an interface and create implementations for HW1 and HW2. Since your code will know in run time the version to select the right HW, using virtual interfaces is the way to go about it.

```
class HwInterface
{
  public:
    virtual void set_port() = 0;
};

class Hw1 : public HwInterface
{
  public:
    void set_port() override
    { 
      ...
    }
};

class Hw2 : public HwInterface
{
  public:
    void set_port() override
    { 
      ...
    }
};

class Logic
{
   public:
     void do_something(HwInterface& hw)
     {
       hw.set_port();
     }
};

void run(int version)
{
  Logic logic;

  if (version == 1) {
    Hw1 hw1;
    logic.do_something(hw1);
  }
  else {
    Hw2 hw2;
    logic.do_something(hw2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That does look reasonable and something I can definitely use. Appreciate your help.

Comment: My pleasure, could you please set the question as answered please? thanks!